# How can an empty cell have formula?

Tags: excel

Imagine a sheet like this:

A1 = 1

B1 = 1

C1 = A1+B1

It has about 20 rows, to make the it work on next rows I have to copy the C1 content and paste it on column C.

But I noticed that I don't need to do that, and every time I put data on A and B column, the column next to B, which is C, automatically sums them up.

For example: In Row 21, C21 is empty, but If I put data in A21 and B21, the C1 automatically sums them up without having any formula in it.

How's that possible?

Comment: You should read up about [Excel relative vs. absolute references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

Comment: Did you mean C21 sums up A21 and B21? And is your data set up as an Excel table?

Comment: Answer is easy, it's the Excel AI. It just recognizes what you were doing previously and continues doing it for you.

Comment: This couls be a worksheet_change event in the worksheet's private code sheet.

Comment: @QHarr Yes it sums them without having any formula, It's like excel is recognizing what I did in previous C cells and it does it for me automatically.

it is not set as an excel table. I don't remember doing that. 

This is a cool feature, I just don't know how does it work and how can I set it for other columns.

Comment: @JvdV Cool, then how can I use it again? for other columns?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot? And as per @Jeeped's comment have you checked the code pane associated with the sheet? If you right click on the tab you are interested in and choose view code.... is there any code in there to view?

Comment: It’s not something you can set (that i’m Aware of) it just start recognizing what you did in previous rows/columns to a certain extent. Just try an empty sheet. Type a value in A1, another in B1. Sum them with a formula in C1. Drag those down like 20 rows. Fill A21, B21 and see the Excel magic spear in C21.

Comment: It’s the same AI that recognizes you have put January. When you would type that and drag it down 12 cells it will also fill up to December. Same for numbers....

Answer (score 0):

If you have a repeating pattern, Excel tries to carry it on for you.

So, if you have headers in `A1`/`B1`/`C2`, numbers in `A2:B20`, and a formula in `C2:C20` to add the values in columns A and B, then type a value in `A21`, hit [Tab], type a value in `B21` and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the Column C formula will automatically be copied into cell `C21`.

Testing exactly that (Add headers, start in `A2`: value, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Value, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, `=RC[-2]+RC[-1]`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, loop), Excel started autofilling in cell `C6` (i.e. the 5th row of data)

Comment: I tried to do what you mentioned above, but I couldn't. Can you check your answer and see if there's a typo? 

`=RC[-2]+RC[-1]`
This formula also didn't work

Comment: @user3712884 Is your Excel set to use `R1C1` notation or `A1` notation?  For row 2, the `A1` version would be `=A2+B2`, for row 3 it would be `=A3+B3`, etc

Answer (score -1):

its possible that you have the autoadd function activated on that cell[Auto-sum Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyUrz.png), which do that add without put any formula.